# osmosis library in java application

Tags: openstreetmap, java, osmosis

I want to do a navigation application OSM PBF files.

I'm using the pbf files from the osm website.

I was looking for a way to access the pbf files, I found that it can be accessed using the osmosis library. But I have no idea on how to use it. and there's no documentation.

Comment: crosspost: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26453735/using-osmosis-library-in-java-application

Answer (score 1):

The OSM OSMOSIS page gives beginner examples under the section marked '[usage](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis#Usage)'. For further documentation try the [detailed usage](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Detailed_Usage) section.

For routing specifically, you may also like to investigate [PgRouting](http://pgrouting.org/) (for which you will need to load your data into PostGIS using OSMOSIS or OSM2PGSQL) or have a look at [OSM2PO](http://osm2po.de/).  Both of these a common routing solutions for OSM data with plenty of tutorials on the web. and discussion in this forum.

Comment: I'd love to do my own routing algorithm. That's why I want to extract the data.

Comment: the detailed usage is for the command line application, I want to use in my   java application.

Comment: You can use command line programs in Java applications, too.

Comment: How to do that  ?

Comment: For example via `ProcessBuilder`. But this is the wrong place for discussing how to execute external programs in Java.